# A new adventure awaits! Let's go!

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, crossword-clues

**UPDATE:** To make this puzzle fairer, the pieces have been modified to include additional hints. If you want to try and solve the puzzle with the original non-clued  pieces, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPHx9.png).

---

> *A tale is being told here, one that spans many years and generations... but what kind of tale might it be?*

[image: new_adventure_clues]

*[Pastebin link to a transcript of the clues](https://pastebin.com/AX3sCJb4), including colorblind assistance. Note that Y = Yellow, B = Black/Gray, R = Red, W = White*

[image: new_adventure_pieces]

*[Click here for a copy of the pieces without the highlighted squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Gvi.png)*

The answer is a **five-letter word.**

---

**Hint 1:**

> This puzzle was posted on February 27, 2021.

**Hint 2:**

> No rotation of the pieces is necessary. When constructed properly, the assembled figure should fit snugly within a 17x17 grid.

**Hint 3:**

> Let's not get ahead of ourselves here: this tail... I mean, *tale*, may seem to be quite electric, but there's something else that we can describe it as.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clue answers:

> [image]

From the clues, we can surmise that

> the puzzle is Pokémon themed: several clues are direct references to it. The yellow and black, with a bit of red, suggests Pikachu's color scheme -- so the goal here is to assemble Pikachu from these pieces.

Assembly is hard at first (especially because some of the clues are ambiguous, and you'll have to figure out the answers as you go). But putting the red pieces together gives a start:

> [image: partial assembly]

And a bit of intuition about what can go where (and experimentation with a few possibilities) led me here:

> [image]
>
>  [image]

And *now* there's a way to more confidently assemble the grid! Part of a message has appeared:

> In the yellow squares we have `[g]ROUND [??]G WATE[r] DARK` - these are all Pokémon types!

So, assembling the pieces (and correcting some errors) gives a final image:

> [image: assembled pikachu]
>
>  And this has all the Pokémon types, except for one: **FAIRY**, which is the answer to the puzzle (and the type of tale this is!)

Answer (score 7):

## Clues (Almost Complete)

Thanks to @Deusovi (**bold**, in the chatroom) and @Stiv (*italics*, in the comments) for some of these answers, and for noticing that the answers should be...

> ...in alphabetical order!
>  [image: words mostly filled in as per format of question; sorry for not being screen-reader-friendly but I couldn't think of another way to do this]
>
>  **Notes/Thoughts**
>  *In [Big Stadium](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Big_Stadium_and_Small_Court) in Nimbasa City, Ace Trainer Charlie has a Galvantula, and "Charlie's" fits alphabetically
>  **A [Stradivarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stradivarius) is a type of violin, and violins don't have frets
>  ***Technically the Pokémon's name is "Magnemite", but since "magnem" isn't a word, I think the intended word is "magnet"

## Theme

> The theme of this question is Pokémon for a few reasons. There are a lot of references to it in the clues/answers: Galvantula, Frufrou, Focus Blast, leaving with 1HP, Magnemite/Magneton, Nitro/Flame Charge, Spatial Rend, Farfetch'd, sprite. February 27 (emphasized by Hint 1) is [Pokémon Day](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Day) and the Pokémon franchise spans multiple years and [generations](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Generation)! Not sure what kind of tale is being told though.... The colour scheme also resembles [Pikachu's](https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0d/025Pikachu.png), which is relevant in the next section.

## Next Steps

> Obviously the rest of the clues need to be filled in. @Deusovi mentioned in the chatroom that the goal of the puzzle is to construct Pikachu using the pieces (without rotating them; notice the square pieces in different orientations). However, there isn't a piece long enough without rotating to cover the four cells "sticking out" in the eight-letter clue, so I think rotating might be necessary.
>
>  @Stiv had a similar idea in the comments, but wondered if the pieces, either when laid on the grid or when rearranged, would spell out the names of Pokémon (the "lax" in "relaxes" is remiscient of "Snorlax"). Taking a look at the four-letter Pokémon (Abra, Aron, Axew, Jynx, Natu, Onix, Sawk, Seel, Snom, Uxie, and Xatu, if you want to cross-check) with the I-tetromino, I couldn't find any possible matches, so if this is the case, it is probably post-rearranging.

Comment: The title is also rot13(gur ynfg jbeqf Cebsrffbe Bnx fnlf gb lbh nf lbhe punenpgre orpbzrf cynlnoyr ng gur fgneg bs gur tnzr)

Comment: Some further thoughts I've been toying with: rot13(Gur pbybhe fpurzr vf IREL 'Cvxnpuh'. Pbafvqre gur erqqvfu oybpxf juvpu ybbx fvzvyne va pbybhe gb gur fgevcrf ba n Cvxnpuh'f onpx - vf vg cbffvoyr jr arrq gb erneenatr gur jbeqf va beqre gb perngr n cvpgher bs bar? Nygreangviryl (be znlor nf jryy) V jbaqre jurgure gur cvrprf jura ynvq ba gur tevq nf vg vf abj be bapr erneenatrq jvyy fcryy bhg gur anzrf bs Cbxrzba gung pna or fcryyrq bhg jvguva vg. Gur YNK va erYNKrq vzzrqvngryl znxrf zr guvax bs Fabeynk...)

Comment: Okay, last thing from me for now (must work!) but I think I'm onto something: rot13(Tvira gur vavgvny yrggref bs znal bs gurfr - abgnoyl gur NN_PP va ebjf 1-5 naq gur U_XYZ va gur zvqqyr - V'z jbaqrevat jurgure gur dhrfgvbaf unir orra neenatrq gb unir nafjref VA NYCUNORGVPNY BEQRE. Guvf jbhyq znxr frireny bs lbhe pheerag nafjref vapbeerpg ng cerfrag, ohg znal pbhyq rnfvyl or svkrq gb svg guvf cnggrea - r.t. 70'f qb = FUNT, Snesrgpu'q srngher = FGNYX, Fbeqvq = TEHOOL/TEBGGL...)

Comment: Me again :) Some suggestions for others that fit with my idea above: rot13(svk hc Sehsebh = PBZO, ertneqyrff = VA FCVGR, nvef = ZVRAF, gvtugrarq = CVAPURQ, bccbfvgr bs erqhpr = CEBYBAT, ehva = HAQBVAT) Not all may be correct - particularly unsure about the Frufrou one.

Comment: @Stiv If you have an opinion, why not share it in the chatroom for this puzzle?

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica Ah, because I had no idea such a chatroom existed! (It would have been useful for someone to have posted beneath the puzzle that there was one...) Now I've seen it I can see that Deusovi and I have had exactly the same idea and have both been working towards the same end. If I can end anything new I will do it [in the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120311/a-new-adventure)...

Comment: Ribbons and badges => njneqf?

Comment: @tmpearce That was what I had before, but it doesn't fit the rot13(nycunorgvpny beqre)

Comment: typo: " "sky" or "high" " should be " "sky" or "fly" " :0

Comment: @oAlt Good eye, thanks! Fixed

Comment: There are some additional hints that have been added to the puzzle, which show that we are recreating the words that are in the puzzle in the pathing boxes. The puzzle should be updated to reflect this as I don't think any suggestions before the hint suggest this.